# Becoming attained-to-view as opposed to one liberated-by-faith and vice versa

Tags: practice

How did the practice of one in-training (*sekha*) differ so that he became one attained-to-view as opposed to one liberated-by-faith and vice versa?

In [MN 70](https://suttacentral.net/mn70/en/sujato) the Buddha describes them like so:

> And what person is attained to view? It’s a person who doesn’t have
> direct meditative experience of the peaceful liberations that are
> formless, transcending form. Nevertheless, having seen with wisdom,
> some of their defilements have come to an end. And they have clearly
> seen and clearly contemplated with wisdom the teaching and training
> proclaimed by the Realized One. This person is called attained to
> view. I say that this mendicant also still has work to do with
> diligence. Why is that? Thinking: ‘Hopefully this venerable will
> frequent appropriate lodgings, associate with good friends, and
> control their faculties. Then they might realize the supreme
> culmination of the spiritual path in this very life, and live having
> achieved with their own insight the goal for which gentlemen rightly
> go forth from the lay life to homelessness.’ Seeing this fruit of
> diligence for this mendicant, I say that they still have work to do
> with diligence. And what person is freed by faith? It’s a person who
> doesn’t have direct meditative experience of the peaceful liberations
> that are formless, transcending form. Nevertheless, having seen with
> wisdom, some of their defilements have come to an end. And their faith
> is settled, rooted, and planted in the Realized One. This person is
> called freed by faith. I say that this mendicant also still has work
> to do with diligence. Why is that? Thinking: ‘Hopefully this venerable
> will frequent appropriate lodgings, associate with good friends, and
> control their faculties. Then they might realize the supreme
> culmination of the spiritual path in this very life, and live having
> achieved with their own insight the goal for which gentlemen rightly
> go forth from the lay life to homelessness.’ Seeing this fruit of
> diligence for this mendicant, I say that they still have work to do
> with diligence.

Comment: Try here: https://suttacentral.net/an3.21/en/sujato?layout=linebyline&reference=pts&notes=asterisk&highlight=true&script=latin

Comment: Here: https://suttacentral.net/pp2.9/en/law?reference=pts&highlight=true

Answer (score 3):

> How did the practice of one in-training (sekha) differ so that he became one attained-to-view as opposed to one liberated-by-faith and vice versa?

Likely that'd involve more than just the training but also the innate orientation of whether one is "insight oriented" or "serenity oriented" as the dominant faculty. Sorta like some folks are born naturally good at literature, while others are naturally good at math. Note that the Liberated-by-Faith/SaddhaVimutta is for those who are "serenity oriented". This stage is a notch below the Attained-to-View/DitthiPatta, who is "insight oriented". Ven. Bodhi in "Middlelength Discourses" provides footnote to those 2 terms based on Commentaries' explanation:

> Attained to View/DitthiPatta(insight oriented): [705]MA: includes the same 6 individuals as under Kayasakkhin, but without possession of immaterial attainments. Pug. defines him as one who has understood the Four Noble Truths, reviewed, examined with wisdom the teachings proclaimed by the Tathagata; defilements partially abandoned without immaterial attainments;
> Liberated by Faith/SaddhaVimutta(serenity oriented): [706]MA: includes the same 6. Pug. defines same way as Ditthipatta, but adds that he has not reviewed and examined the teachings with wisdom to the same extent that the Ditthipatta has; defilements partially abandoned without immaterial attainments;[ITBW_X.17]This includes the same classes in whom faith is the dominant faculty.

Comment: Ok, but what does it mean that your practice is more serenity based as opposed to insight. Does it  insight practice require more study and reflection? And the faith based more just quietening the mind to stop mental activity. Also how is the faith based practice it seems more like what the body witness would be doing.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker, just like the folks naturally good at either literature or math, you'll find folks who naturally oriented toward investigative/contemplative approach (ie. the insight track), and those who are naturally oriented toward faith, peace, and serenity/tranquility approach. The Body-Witness is actually a notch above just faith-based, but actually requires one to also attain one of those immaterial-attainments (Infinte-space, infinite-concsiousness, nothingness, or neither-perception-nor-non-perception). So naturally, these would require a high degree of serenity/tranquitlity/faith